Программа - рисует окошко из символов введенных пользователем
Напишите программу, которая рисует окошко из символов, введенных пользователем. Например, если пользователь введет звездочку, то окошко будет выглядеть так:

1 урок, только начал работать с пайтоном
все что мог сделать:\
symbol = input("Введите символ для окошка: ")

print('       ')\
print('       ')\
print('       ')\
print('       ')\
print('       ')\
print('       ')\
print('       ')

версия Python 3.13.0

Почему введенный пользователем символ у вас нигде не используется?

я пробовал, но что то не получалось

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

def draw_window(symbol, size):
 for row in range(size * 2 + 1):
  if row % size == 0:
   print(f"{symbol} " * (size * 2 + 1))
  else:
   print(f"{symbol}{' ' * (size * 2 - 1)}{symbol}{' ' * (size * 2 - 1)}{symbol}")
    
# Пример использования
user_symbol = input("Введите символ: ") 
user_size = int(input("Введите размер квадрата: "))  
draw_window(user_symbol, user_size) 

Объяснение:

Определение функции draw_window(symbol, size). Параметры: symbol (символ для рисования), size (размер квадрата).
Цикл for row in range(size * 2 + 1). Проходит по строкам окна (всего size * 2 + 1 строк).
Условие if row % size == 0. Проверяет, является ли строка границей квадрата.
Печать границы квадрата print(f"{symbol} " * (size * 2 + 1)). Печатает строку с символами для верхней или нижней границы.
Печать боковых границ квадрата print(f"{symbol}{' ' * (size * 2 - 1)}{symbol}{' ' * (size * 2 - 1)}{symbol}"). Печатает строку с символами для боковых границ и пробелами между ними.
Пример использования. Запрос символа и размера квадрата у пользователя.

